# jQuery onclick check if clicked area has child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've multiple div's in in div. These div's has all the same name:

```
<div class="remodal-wrapper remodal-is-opened" style="display: block;">
    <div class="remodal remodal-is-initialized remodal-is-opened" data-remodal-id="success-modal" tabindex="-1">
        CONTENT ONE
    </div>
</div>

<div class="remodal-wrapper remodal-is-closed" style="display: none;">
    <div class="remodal remodal-is-initialized remodal-is-opened" data-remodal-id="error-modal" tabindex="-1">
        CONTENT TWO
    </div>
</div>
```

Because I need to do a `location.reload();` when the user clicks on the wrapper where `child = data-remodal-id="success-modal"` I need to build an `onclick function`.

The problem is that I'm using a library for a modal here and all the wrappers has the same class names. So is it possible to do something like:

```
jQuery('.remodal-wrapper -> where child = data-remodal-id="success-modal"').click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select any children of the wrapper.

```
jQuery('.remodal-wrapper div[data-remodal-id="success-modal"]').click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

or if you need it to be especially a direct children:

```
jQuery('.remodal-wrapper > div[data-remodal-id="success-modal"]').click(function () {
    location.reload();
});
```

In vanilla JS you'd use `querySelectorAll` and then `forEach`... I hope this answers your question.